# Case In Where Condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following data in my Product table

```
Proj_No   Category  Attribute1
X567       SubInv   No      
X946       SubInv   No
X912       US       No
```

I need to extract only those rows which are having category column = SubInv and Atrribute1 = No

I have tried as

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN category = 'SubInv'
            THEN 'No'
        ELSE NULL
        END ATTRIBUTE1
```

For the above, I am getting

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Good practice to check if it's always 'No' you may find it sometimes being 'NO' or 'No ' with extra spaces... to answer your question you need to put column that you are evaluating directly after CASE keyword. You don't need to evaluate within WHEN and THEN operators. (case category when SubInv then No else null end)

Comment: Tip of today: don't use case expressions in the WHERE clause, use AND/OR instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not evaluating the result of your `CASE` with anything. I think you mean:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCTS 
WHERE CASE WHEN category = 'SubInv' THEN 'No' ELSE NULL END = ATTRIBUTE1
```

But you don't need a `CASE` for this at all. See other answers.

Comment: Your welcome, but as said, for a query like this you're better of using `and/or` logic.

Comment: @user75ponic Why are you using a case here? you don't need it

Comment: @Downvoter: Is your issue that this problem doesn't need a case? If so, I mentioned that (even referred to other answers). If not, what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need case for this.

```
select *
from your_table
where Category = 'SubInv'
and Attribute1 = 'No';
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a `case` for this?  `AND` is so much simpler and clearer

```
SELECT p.*
FROM PRODUCTS p
WHERE category = 'SubInv' AND Atrribute1 = 'No'
```